Which commutative rings are endomorphism rings of some topological Abelian group?
I was thinking earlier today about how many commutative unital rings I could hit by considering the endomorphism rings of topological Abelian groups.
For example, the group $(\mathbb{R}, +, \tau^R)$ where $\tau^R$ is the standard topology on the reals has $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ as its endomorphism ring; the continuity restriction is enough to rule out potential wild endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$. We can scale the real line linearly, but we can't do anything else without breaking continuity or not being a group homomorphism.
According to this question and this answer if I start with the endomorphism rings of every Abelian group and allow quotienting by an ideal, then we can hit every ring.
This makes me wonder what we can hit if we take away the ability to take homomorphic images but add the ability to specify a topological structure on our Abelian group.

Here is an old statement with a partial answer to your question:
Let $R$ be a unital ring whose additive group is finitely generated, then there exists an abelian topological group A for which $\operatorname{End}(A)\cong R$.
